# Clustering points based on maximum distance to each cluster center

Tags: qgis, spatial-cluster

I have a layer of buildings (points). I would like cluster as many of them as I can around a common point in space in such a way that all the members of each cluster have a maximum distance of 100 m to their common point.

Can this be done in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the closest solution is to use the tool 'Nearest Neighbours Cluster Map' from the [**Visualist plugin**](https://analysecriminelle.org/main/). According to the tool description, it is "*a simplified version of the algorithm in [CrimeStat](https://nij.ojp.gov/topics/articles/crimestat-spatial-statistics-program-analysis-crime-incident-locations) from Ned Levine*".

You can set the maximum distance between points, and the minimum cluster size.

This was the only solution I found that ensured that all points in the cluster were within a defined distance among all of them. In other alternatives, like DBSCAN clustering, you can define a maximum distance among points, but this is applied only individually, i.e., as long as the next point is within that distance, it will be added to the cluster, even if the distance to other points already in the cluster is larger.

To understand the difference, imagine a 10km road, with lamp posts within 100m from each other. If you use DBSCAN clustering and set the maximum distance at 101m, all the points would be included in one single cluster, even though the first and last points could be 10km apart.
The Visualist plugin uses a recursive algorithm, trying to [find the best solution for the cluster groups](https://analysecriminelle.org/main/#nearest-neighbours-clusters-map).

Figure below shows an example of clusters defined with Visualist. Maximum distance was set to 100m. The orange polygons correspond to calculated clusters. Numbers inside the grey circles correspond to the total number of points in each cluster (orange dots). Black dots correspond to individual points outside any cluster, i.e., points distanced more than 100m from other points.

In the image, you can see that many clusters are closer than 100m from each other, with some points very close to points from another cluster. But if you consider the centroid from the clusters, all of them are apart from each other over 100m. This recursive method tries to optimise the distribution of points per clusters.

[image: Example of clusters defined with Visualist.]